# Is there a way to handle spaces during output in table form for C lang?

Tags: arrays, c, string

This is my code and here I'm unable to manage the spaces in the header in my output when I was converting in table form.
Here is what I did :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter no of students : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int marks1[n], marks2[n],rollno[n];
    float avg=0, total=0;
    char name[5][10];
    char grade;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter name %d : ",(i+1));
        scanf("%s",name[i]);
        printf("Enter roll no  : ");
        scanf("%d",&rollno[i]);
        printf("Enter Marks1 of student %d : ",(i+1));
        scanf("%d",&marks1[i]);
        printf("Enter marks2 of student %d : ",(i+1));
        scanf("%d",&marks2[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n                                          Student Records                                               \n");
    printf("Name \t Roll No \t       Marks1 \t          Marks2 \t    Total \t   Avg \t Grade \n");
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        total = marks1[i] + marks2[i];
        avg = (marks1[i] + marks2[i])/2;
        if(avg >= 85) { 
            grade = 'S'; 
        } else if (avg >=70 && avg < 85) { 
            grade = 'A'; 
        } else if (avg < 70 && avg>=60) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (avg >= 50 && avg < 60) {
            grade = 'C';
        }  else {
            grade = 'F';
        }
        printf("%-8s | %-14d | %-14d | %-9d | %-7.2f | %-8.2f | %-7c\n", name[i], rollno[i], marks1[i], marks2[i], total, avg, grade);
        avg=0;
        total=0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
Enter no of students : 1
Enter name 1 : raju
Enter roll no  : 22
Enter Marks1 of student 1 : 78
Enter marks2 of student 1 : 98

                                          Student Records                                               
Name     Roll No           Marks1             Marks2        Total      Avg   Grade 
raju     | 22             | 78             | 98        | 176.00  | 88.00    | S
```

Is there any method to handle the spaces during Input ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using tabs in your header, but explicit widths in the numerical output. It's up to the console how to print tabs. If you want more control over your output, use the same explicit widths for header and data.

For example:

```
// header
printf("%-8s | %-14s | %-14s |  ...\n", "Name", "Roll No", "Marks");

// data rows
printf("%-8s | %-14d | %-14d | ...\n", name[i], rollno[i], marks[i]);
```